# NSViewController New vs. InitWithNibName issues

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, appkit

I am having a weird error with NSViewController where if I allocate a view using the viewcontroller's regular init message, the view created is not my view, but when using the default NIB name, it does work.

Specifically, this code works all the time. It creates the view defined in the nib file, and displays it in the parentView.

```
+ (void)createTransparentViewCenteredInView:(NSView*)parentView withText:(NSString*)text duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    TransparentAccessoryViewController* controller = [[TransparentAccessoryViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TransparentAccessoryViewController" bundle:nil];

    NSLog(@"%@", [controller.view class]);    // Returns "TransparentAccessoryView" -- CORRECT
    [parentView addSubview:controller.view];
}
```

However, the following code works SOME of the time (which is weird in that it doesn't always fail). With some parentViews, it works perfectly fine, and with others, it doesn't. The parent views are just random custom NSViews.

```
+ (void)createTransparentViewCenteredInView:(NSView*)parentView withText:(NSString*)text duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    TransparentAccessoryViewController* controller = [TransparentAccessoryViewController new];

    NSLog(@"%@", [controller.view class]);    // Returns "NSSplitView" -- INCORRECT
    [parentView addSubview:controller.view];
}
```

The errors that comes up are as follows (I have no idea why it is bringing up an NSTableView, as I don't have an NSTableView here at all. Also, it is weird that it complains about an NSTableView when the type it prints is an NSSplitView):

> 2013-04-07 21:33:12.384 Could not connect the action refresh: to
>   target of class TransparentAccessoryViewController
>
> 2013-04-07 21:33:12.384 Could not connect the action remove: to target
>   of class TransparentAccessoryViewController
>
> 2013-04-07 21:33:12.385  *** Illegal NSTableView data source
>   ().  Must implement
>   numberOfRowsInTableView: and tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:

The NIB file defines a custom subclassed NSView, called TransparentAccessoryView, and hooks this up to the File Owner's view property, standard stuff (all I did was change the custom class name to TransparentAccessoryView). I added an NSLog's to see what was going on, and for some reason, in the second case, the view class type is incorrect and thinks it is an NSSplitView for some reason. The ViewController class is as follows:

```
@implementation TransparentAccessoryViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    self.textField.stringValue = @"";
}

+ (void)createTransparentViewCenteredInView:(NSView*)parentView withText:(NSString*)text duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    TransparentAccessoryViewController* controller = [[TransparentAccessoryViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TransparentAccessoryViewController" bundle:nil];

    NSLog(@"%@", [controller.view class]);
    [parentView addSubview:controller.view];
}

@end
```

I thought that the default init message triggers the viewcontroller to load the NIB named after the viewcontroller, which seems to be the case some of the time as the second version of my code works in certain conditions.

Does anyone know why this behavior is occurring at all?

Comment: Where are you getting that the default implementation of `init` on NSViewController simply calls `initWithNibName:bundle` with the appropriate nib and bundle? `init:withNibName:bundle` is the designated initializer for that class, and I would think that `init` simply calls `initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil`

Comment: This [site](http://twobitlabs.com/2012/01/initializing-uiviewcontrollers/) says that "Then it’s up to MyController to determine how to initialize its view. If you don’t override init, iOS will by convention look for a nib with the same name as the controller (in this case MyController.xib)." I know this is for iOS, and can't quickly find a link to this for NSViewControllers, but all my other NSViewControllers are alloc'd and initialized with the `new` parameter and it always loads the NIB named after the ViewController.

Comment: try checking the property `nibName` for your custom viewController after its initialized with `[TransparentAccessoryViewController new]` to see what nib it actually loaded. The link mentions that the implementation of `init` for view controllers is undocumented and might change in future versions of the SDK

Comment: I guess that UIViewController and NSViewController is different.

Comment: I use the 'new' shortcut throughout my programs for initializing viewcontrollers and it works as expected. Even this code works with the `new' sometimes. I guess I'm wondering why it doesn't always work or better yet, why it doesn't always fail.

Answer (score 2):

From [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSViewController_Class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSViewController/initWithNibName%3abundle%3a):

> If you pass in a nil for nibNameOrNil then nibName will return nil and
>   loadView will throw an exception; in this case you must invoke
>   setView: before view is invoked, or override loadView.

Therefore, if you're initializing a `NSViewController` with `-init`, you should call `-setView:` to set the view controller's view, or override `-loadView`. In the latter case, you could certainly implement the `UIViewController`-like behavior that you're probably expecting -- if `nibNameOrNil` is nil, try to load a nib that has the same name as the class.

Answer (score 1):

I think that when you call `init` on a NSViewController, you're assuming that the implementation of `init` for NSViewController searches for a nib with the same name as the view controller and uses it. However, this is undocumented API or at least I can't seem to find any documentation supporting that assumption. The [link](http://twobitlabs.com/2012/01/initializing-uiviewcontrollers/) you posted on your comments doesn't cite any documentation either and even reiterates that this is undocumented and that Apple could change this implementation at any point.

I think to assure that your code works in future versions of the SDK (and since it is already creating undesired behavior), you should not rely on this assumption. To achieve the same outcome simply override `init` and `initWithNibName:bundle:` in such a way as explained by [this post](http://oleb.net/blog/2012/01/initWithNibName-bundle-breaks-encapsulation/):

```
@implementation MyCustomViewController

// This is now the designated initializer
- (id)init
{
    NSString *nibName = @"MyCustomViewController";
    NSBundle *bundle = nil;
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibName bundle:bundle];
    if (self) {
        ...
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)bundle
{
    // Disregard parameters - nib name is an implementation detail
    return [self init];
}
```